# How to run a 60sec countdown timer or open a countdown.php when new data is inserted on database and I'm using a real time data display?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Countdown.php // I get it somewhere from the internet

```
<script>
function countDown(secs,elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
    if(secs < 1) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown Complete!</h2>';
        element.innerHTML += '<a href="#">Click here now</a>';
    }
    secs--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")',1000);
}
</script>
<div id="status"></div>
<script>countDown(60,"status");</script>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Real Time Data Display</title>
  </head>
  <body onload = "table();">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function table(){
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function(){
          document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "system.php");
        xhttp.send();
      }

      setInterval(function(){
        table();
      }, 5000);
    </script>
    <div id="table">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

system.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "user");
$rows = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users_logs");
?>
<table border = 1 cellpadding = 10>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>user</td>
    <td>Plate</td>
    <td>age</td>
    <td>email</td>
  </tr>
  <?php $i = 1; ?>
  <?php foreach($rows as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $i++; 
 $link = "<script>window.open('http://localhost/realtimedatadisplay/countdown.php')</script>";
 echo $link;
?>
</td>
      <td><?php echo $row["user"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["plate"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["age"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "user");
$rows = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users_logs");

$query = "SELECT * FROM users_logs";
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "user");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$link = "<script>window.open('http://localhost/realtimedatadisplay/countdown.php')</script>";

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        $check = $_SESSION['user'] = $num_rows;
    } else {
        $check = $_SESSION['user'];
    }
    echo $num_rows;
     if($num_rows > $check ) { 
        $check = $_SESSION['user'] = $num_rows;
        echo "new user";
        echo $link;
     } else {
        echo "wait";
     }
        
?>
```

I'm a beginer in programming I read and research but nothing comes up close.
The page is active and when a new data insert to database some modal or popup or a new page will appear and start counting down from 1min to 0 and then close, then wait for a new inserted data then again a countdown begin.

Comment: If you set an Interval of 1 millisecond to run the XHR code you will overload your webserver with millions of simultaneous requests. That's not realistic. Try reducing the interval to, say 10 seconds, at minimum. Consider, for your use case, precisely how frequent the updates need to be. If you need anything with less latency than that, you'll need to re-architect your application to use websockets instead...but that is not really a beginner project. Don't bite off more than you can chew...get your foundational web coding knowledge in place with simpler tasks, before attempting the fancy stuff

Comment: 10 sec at minimum, Got it!. After the countdown expected in 5 sec inverval. Mmm. is there an easy way to do it? like a countdown notification or an alert after when a new data is inserted? I hope you'll consider my problem.  Thank you

Comment: If you want to monitor when new data is inserted, you must either 1) keep asking the server for new data periodically, via AJAX. You'd probably need to send it the ID of the last record you received, and make PHP/SQL only return records added after that. Then, if you get results back, you will know there are new records. Or 2) Have a similar PHP script again, except that it runs in the background continuously on you server, and  then make it send a websocket message (which your page is listening to) to show when new data has arrived. Like I said, this is not a good topic for a total beginner

Comment: How about on how to open a countdown.php when a new data is inserted to database? Thank you!

Comment: Well, you'd do that in your JS code - when it receives the response from PHP and realises there is new data, it can open countdown.php (just use the `window.open` command in JS if you want to open a separate window)

Comment: Yes, I've tried 'window.open' but it does'nt work. Maybe I put the 'window.open' in the wrong sequence. Can I see how you do it? Please.  Thank you.

Comment: "doesn't work" could mean anything. Show me the code you actually wrote. Do you get a console error when it runs? What happens instead? Did you use the JS debugger in your browser to ensure that command was definitely executed? If you don't know how to use your browser's Developer Tools to debug your JS code, that's something you need to learn before you go any further. Like I said above, you seem to be trying to run before you can walk. Learn the basics, and _then_ attempt some complicated feature like this. And learn to describe things in more detail than "doesn't work" so it's meaningful

Comment: P.S. You don't need to see how _I_ use window.open, because there are more than enough examples [in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). It would be more instructive to see how _you_ used it, in case you did something obviously wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, Please excuse my Grammar, English is my third language. I get what you mean. maybe I just read some more.

Comment: It's not a grammar problem, your grammar is ok. The problem is that you did not describe the issue with enough detail for us to understand the problem, and did not provide any code so that we could possibly see the problem, either.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I dont know how to post my test codes.

Comment: To post code properly, you need to [edit] your question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouputting a `window.open` command in a script within your PHP loop won't achieve what you want. This will simply cause that script tag to be generated for every row in your database, every time your PHP script is executed.

As I suggested in the comments, if you want to find out if a new row (or rows) has been added to the database since the last time you queried the server, you will need to maintain a JS variable in your page which knows the last row ID it received from the database, and then sends that back to the server so it knows where to start serving rows from next. N.B. This assumes that your database table has an ID column which is generated by auto-increment. If your table doesn't have such a column already, you will need to add it before this can work. The JS code would then need to look at the response it receives, see how many new rows were returned, and if at least one is returned it can start the timer. It's easier to do this if PHP returns the data in JSON format, and JS creates the HTML table from it.

I assumed also that, since the timer lasts 60 seconds, there is no point in polling for any new rows from the server until that has finished. (Although, it's unclear what the purpose of the timer is, so that may be a mistaken assumption. If so, adjust the interval timer according to your needs, but don't make it so frequent that it overloads the server with multiple parallel requests.)

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Real Time Data Display</title>
  </head>
  <body onload = "table();">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var lastID = 0; //track the last record ID received from the server

      function table()
      {
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function() {
          var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    
          if (result.length > 0) 
          {
            window.open("countdown.php"); //open the countdown if needed
    
            var html = '';
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
              html += "<tr>";
              html += "<td>" + result[i].id + "</td>";
              html += "<td>" + result[i].user + "</td>";
              html += "<td>" + result[i].plate + "</td>";
              html += "<td>" + result[i].age + "</td>";
              html += "<td>" + result[i].email + "</td>";
              html += "</tr>";
              lastID = result[i].id;
            }
            document.querySelector("#resultsTable tbody").innerHTML += html;
           }
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "system.php?lastID=" + lastID);
        xhttp.send();
      }

      setInterval(function() {
        table();
      }, 60000);
    </script>

    <div id="table">
      <table id="resultsTable" border="1" cellpadding="10">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>user</th>
            <th>Plate</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**system.php**

```
//get the submitted last ID, or default to 0 if not provided
if (isset($_GET["lastID"]) { $lastID = $_GET["lastID"]; }
else { $lastID = 0; }

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "user");

//get all rows which are later than the last ID
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_logs WHERE id > ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $lastID);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//encode the array of rows in JSON format
echo json_encode($rows);
```

---

N.B. As also discussed in the comments, this polling solution using AJAX is the simplest to achieve, but is unlikely to scale up well. In a bigger or more heavily-used website, it would be sensible to investigate using Websockets, or at least Server-Sent Events, to deliver the real-time updates to the browser, in order to avoid performance problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I really appreciate your tips and the knowledge youre sharing, but I were not able to understand it yet.

Comment: Also when I tried it. It just incrementing a row every 6 sec saying an undifined. when I insert a data nothing happends. also I put self.close(); on countdown.php. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not getting to grasp  the code yet, maybe, just maybe I will sometime/someday. I'm try to understand it a line at a time. but what it did to my end is that when a new record is inserted, it add rows(undefined) and  open countdown.php. even theres no data inserted to database.

Comment: Sorry the 6 seconds was my mistake, it should be 60 seconds. I have corrected it in the answer. And what _exactly_ does the error message about "undefined" say when you receive it, and where exactly does it appear? (You can upload a screenshot on imgur if it's easier to show it that way)

Comment: P.S. If there are any specific parts of the code you are not sure about, and, after going through it line by line, you are still unsure, please let me know and I will try to explain it

Comment: I'm really thankful for your responds. This is the link of my remaining  error --> https://imgur.com/PhN9nSk

Comment: also it adds row every time I click the page. is there a way that it wont happend? Also, I would like to know why it happend.  Thank you again.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you saying that it adds a row every time you click your mouse anywhere on the page? My code would not do that, it must be something else. Or do you mean something else? Your description "click the page" was not very clear about that issue.

Comment: As for the "undefined" problem, that must mean the response from the server doesn't have the expected structure / contents. After `xhttp.onload = function() {`, please add to your code  `console.log(this.responseText);` and then check in the browser's Console to see what the result actually contains, and let me know.

Comment: Hi! After I add console.log(this.responseText); nothing changes. this is the link--> https://imgur.com/a/d7lTz1I     Thank you.

Comment: You have to open the browser's Developer Tools and look in the console to see the output of that command. Sorry that is quite a basic JS thing, I assumed you knew what to do

Comment: Hi, I just got home.. here's the link..  --> https://imgur.com/a/BRsWUQN

Comment: I'm worried that maybe it is in my side has a problem.. but I double check what could be I mislook. Thanks again..

Comment: Yes you do have a big problem. On line 8 of the system.php file, PHP is failing to connect to your database, as the error is telling you. I don't know if that's the line `$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "user");` that I gave you (copied from the one in your original code) or something else you have added?

Comment: Also, I made a small mistake too. `$rows = $result->fetch_all();` should be `$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` , so we get an associative array back from MySQL. That should help with the "undefined" problem ( as I can see from the console data that the array is just a numerically indexed one, not an associative one with named keys). I have updated the answer.

Comment: It works!!!!!!! I dont know what to say. The problem is on my part I replaced it to $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); and assigned its variables. I'm so sorry, I lack experience. I should practice more. Thank you and thank you again for your patience.

Comment: No problem. I hope you learned a few things from this along the way!

Comment: Yes!! and a lot. And a very happy Thank you!